# Xpath comparions in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

So I have dead ended on trying to figure out how to do value comparisons,

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" ><xsl:output ndent="no"     method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="/">
Famous Mountains of the World
<xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="mountain">
<xsl:apply-templates select="name[@language='English']" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="height" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="name[@language='English']">
 name: <xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="height">
Height:<xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My out put ends up looking like

```
Famous Mountains of the World

Name: Mount Everest
Height:29035
Name: Mount Ranier
Height:14411
Name: Mount St. Helens
Height:8364
Name: Mount Washington
Height:6288
Name: Mount Bonnell
Height:800
Name: Mount Vesuvius
Height:4203
Name: Mount Etna
Height:10922
```

Its close but I am supposed to end up with this. Because I keep butchering the comparison operators.

```
Name: Mount Everest
Height: 29035
Name: Mount Ranier
Height: 14411
Name: Mount St. Helens
Height: 8364
Name: Mount Washington
Height: 6288
Name: Mount Bonnell
Height less than 801 feet

Name: Mount Vesuvius
Height: 4203
Name: Mount Etna
Height: 10922
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Specifically the  less than 801 output.

Here is the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Note: This is a comment-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Asg09.xsl"?>
<FamousMountains>
 <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Everest</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa verestEa</name>
    <location>Nepal</location>
    <height units="feet">29035</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
   <name language="English">Mount Ranier</name>
    <location>Washington</location>
    <height units="feet">14411</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount St. Helens</name>
    <location>Washington</location>
    <height units="feet">8364</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Washington</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa ashingtonWa</name>
    <location>New Hampshire</location>
    <height units="feet">6288</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Bonnell</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa onnellBa</name>
    <location>Austin</location>
    <height units="feet">800</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Vesuvius</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa esuviusVa</name>
    <location>Italy</location>
    <height units="feet">4203</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Etna</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa tnaEa</name>
    <location>Sicily</location>
    <height units="feet">10922</height>
  </mountain>
</FamousMountains>
```

Just trying to figure out how to differentiate between certain numbers, in this case numbers less than 801 so like the mountain being 800. Height less than 801 feet for  Mount bonnel.

Comment: Could you formulate a question here? Seeing the XML input would also help.

Comment: one sec my xml exploded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="height[. &lt; 800]">
Height: less than 800 feet
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Perhaps alter both of the 800 to 801 to match the question better?

Comment: I think when someone is so vague in their specification, it's fair to let them sort out the detail.

Comment: Thank you and it wasn't my intention to be vague just didn't explain myself better.